# How to add a smart watch/bracelet to a flutter app?

Tags: flutter, apple-watch

I'm writtig the code for my new fitness app.
I would like to add the feature to connect the app with a smart band (watch/bracelet). Is it possible to do this? And is it possible to count with this informations?

How to do this?
Is there a universal plugin/method or is there one for Apple Watches, one for Samsung, one for Huawei/Honor and so on?